# Sorting three lists using the ordering from one of them in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting

Given three distinct lists of the same length, I want to sort all three of them, using the ordering from one of them. For example, for the given three lists:

```
val a = Seq(2, 1, 3)
val b = Seq("Hi", "there", "world")
val c = Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

...and assuming that we sort by the ordering from `a`, I want the result to look like this:

```
aSorted: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3) // Sorted by its own order
bSorted: Seq[String] = List("there", "Hi", "world") // Reordered the same way as aSorted
cSorted: Seq[Double] = List(2.0, 1.0, 3.0) // Reordered the same way as aSorted
```

All functions from `Sorting` appear to work on sequences without any way to specify a `swap` operation. So do I have to resort to writing my own code to sort? Or should I implement some custom sequence type? If so, how?

Comment: If there continues to be a one-to-one correspondence between the three lists, you might want to consider re-modelling as one list of case class instances?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this pretty cleanly with `zip`, `sortBy`, and `unzip`.

```
val (aSorted, pair) = a.zip(b.zip(c)).sortBy(_._1).unzip
val (bSorted, cSorted) = pair.unzip
```

`zip` takes two sequences and returns a sequence of pairs (dropping any extra elements if the lengths don't match). This means `b.zip(c)` is a sequence of `(String, Double)` elements, and `a.zip(b.zip(c))` is a sequence of `(Int, (String, Double))`.

We can then use `sortBy(_._1)` to sort this sequence by the elements from the first sequence.

Lastly `unzip` just undoes `zip`, turning a sequence of `(Int, (String, Double))` into a pair of sequences—one of `Int` elements and one of `(String, Double)` elements. Then we just do the same operation again on the second of these two sequences, and you've got the result you want.